# Status code vs. Response Header Status: what is the rule for bots?

Tags: google, googlebot, http-headers

Assuming we have a page, which has as Status Code `200 OK` and as Response Headers Status `HTTP/1.1 410 Gone`, like on image:

[image]

What is the behavior of bots / Googlebot? To crawl/index or not?

Answer (score 1):

Bots should see the same as what you are seeing in the browser and interpret the response in the same way. ie. as a `200 OK`. That is, after all, what the HTTP Status-Line (the first line of the response header) is reporting - which is part of the [HTTP standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.2).

The `Status` HTTP response *header* is non-standard. (It's less common to see the "HTTP version" specified in this field as well?)